# Replace useSelector with createStructuredSelector in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, reselect

I use reselect library with my react-native project. I have the following code.

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { ApplicationState } from 'types/reducer.types';

const selectAuth = ({ auth }: ApplicationState) => auth;

export const selectFirstName = createSelector([selectAuth], auth => auth.user?.firstName);

export const selectLastName = createSelector([selectAuth], auth => auth?.user?.lastName);
```

In the container the code is like this.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
// import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

import { signOut } from 'Redux/auth/auth.actions';
import { selectFirstName, selectLastName } from 'Redux/auth/auth.selectors';
import CustomDrawer from './custom-drawer.component';

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  firstName: selectFirstName,
  lastName: selectLastName,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { signOut })(CustomDrawer);
```

Now I want to use useSelector hook. I tried several ways but it didn't work. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createStructuredSelector` returns a selector (a function that takes `state` and returns an object `{firstName, lastName}`), so you can use it inside of `useSelector`

```
const {firstName, lastName} = useSelector(createStructuredSelector({
  firstName: selectFirstName,
  lastName: selectLastName,
}));
```

or using your existing variable

```
const {firstName, lastName} = useSelector(mapStateToProps);
```

However there's not really any point in combining and then destructing the properties when you can use many `useSelector` hooks in one component.

```
const firstName = useSelector(selectFirstName);

const lastName = useSelector(selectLastName);
```

Comment: adding to this, you should not use `createSelector` or `createStructuredSelector` directly within a `useSelector` call, as that will create a new selector every time, completely neglecting any benefits you get from using a mempoized selector in the frist place.

Answer (score 0):

`useSelector` and `useDispatch` are two hooks that can be imported from `react-redux` package and these two can easily replace the need for using `connect`.

Here is how you can use them:

```
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {someAction} from '../user/userActions';

const YourComponent = () => {
 // useDispatch returns back a dispatch function
 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 // useSelector selects a portion of the state, it plays the role and 
// replace the need for mapStateToProps in connect higher order function
 const currentUser = useSelector(state => state.user.currentUser);

 return(
   <>
      <h1>{ currentUser.firstName }</h1>
      // Here you can use dispatch to dispatch an action
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(someAction)}></button>
   </>
 )
};

export default YourComponent;
```

Overall, you can see that by using `useSelector` and `useDispatch` we removed so much boilerplate from our code(connect, mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, createStructuredSelector removed) and it looks clean and more readable and still works as previous.

Here is the official resource you can read more about the two above-mentioned hooks.
[React-Redux Hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#hookshttps://)

P.S. You can also send a selector created using `reselect` or whatever selector of your choice into `useSelector`.